# file list sort by modified time in android [using sketchware]

Tags: java, android, datetime, file-sorting

im trying to get a file list at the directory `"/storage/emulated/0/tmp/subtmp/"`
then **sort** it in **newest first** order./get sorted list stating itself.

[image]
^ this is the order I'm trying to achieve.

```bash
fourth
third
first
last
second
```

^this is what i get using,
[image]
*OR*
[image]

> I tried using `lastModified()` but it errors, looks like, there is no `File` data type...

> so i tried to fetch `view-source:` `file:///storage/emulated/0/tmp/subtmp/`
> [image]
> ,which contains modified date & time.
> *but*
> that **didn't** happened..

> then i tried using [ls command],

```java
try {

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -t /storage/emulated/0/tmp/subtmp/"); 

edittext.setText("done");

} catch (Exception e ) {

edittext.setText("not done");
ans.setText(e.toString());

}
```

> and

```java
try {

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -t /storage/emulated/0/tmp/subtmp/ > /storage/emulated/0/tmp/output.txt"); //to read and delete

edittext.setText("done");

} catch (Exception e ) {

edittext.setText("not done");
ans.setText(e.toString());

}
```

> but,.. no new files are created on `/storage/emulated/0/tmp/`

---

### so, is it possible to sort files in sketchware

- it doesnt have any block to get sorted list
- it does have a **add source directly** block

Comment: Can you use the result from "ls" , parse it, sort it, and then save the result where you need it? Also, can you use `new File(...).listFiles()` instead of using "ls" command? Makes it less work as you won't need to parse the result of "ls" command...

Comment: errors like, `File cannot be resolved to a type`

Comment: So import it. It's this one: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html , so you need to add `import java.io.File;` .

Comment: It Not possible to import anything in Sketchware, other than what it had imported according to blocks, components we used in development.  *Import block* is only available in mods

Comment: So use directly instead of importing , meaning `new java.io.File(...).listFiles()`

Answer (score 0):

I face same issue in show last edited image in first of all [SORT BY TIME], I found solution for me and this code will be help into sort arraylist by time.

```java
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
  public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
      return o1.getDateTime().compareTo(o2.getDateTime());
  }
});
```